# How can you detect that you are logged out with the Google login API?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-api-client, google-api-javascript-client

I am using the Google login client API for JavaScript. The site I am working on has two relevant pages. It has a login page, and it has a user profile page. The login page obviously has a Google login button on it. You should only be able to view your profile page when you are logged in. When a user goes to their profile page without being logged in, it should redirect them to the login page.

Here is an approach I have tried that did not work:

```
// This does not work because this event is only fired when the user logs in or logs out, but not when the user is already logged out.
gapi.auth2.init().isSignedIn.listen(function(state) {
    if(!state) location.href = "/login/";
});
```

I have also tried detecting the login status of the user when the script loads, but that did not work either. It always redirected to the login page because the Google API can never log the user in by the time the script is done loading.

Additionally, I am trying not to use `setInterval` or `setTimeout` in my code, though, if that is my only valid option, please inform me.

By the way, I have heard multiple times that I can just set a variable when the user logs in, and then simply redirect to the login page if the variable is `false`. When would I check for the value of said variable? This will not work because it requires me to set a specific delay with `setTimeout`. Google's loading time can vary greatly, so I am not going to use that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out that you can use this simple expression that returns either `true` or `false` depending on whether the user is logged into Google on your website.

```
gapi.auth2.init().isSignedIn.get()
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert in the Google login API, however from the what I do know the API is purely for verification purposes, and (as far as I'm aware, I could be wrong) not actual user sessions. Everything else relating to the user account (IE, storing and persisting the login session in your case) are handled by you, the developer. The basic auth supports calling a callback function on a successful login, via `data-onsuccess`, which calls a JavaScript function on the login with the relevant login information. When a user logins the standard practice is to verify the validity of the user token returned, then you can do what you need with the data. In this case, you'd start some kind of session for the user.

A very basic example is as follows:

> home page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Home</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="/login">Login</a><br>
        <a href="/profile">Profile</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

This has 2 links, one for the profile and one for the login page.

> login/index.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Login</title>
        <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR-CLIENT-ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onLoginSuccess"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function onLoginSuccess(user) {
                var user_id_token = user.getAuthResponse().id_token,
                    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                request.open('POST', 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo');
                request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                request.onload = function() {
                    authUser(request.responseText);
                };
                request.send('id_token=' + user_id_token);
            }
            function authUser(userData) {
                var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                request.open('POST', '/login/login.php');
                request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                request.onload = function() {
                    if (request.responseText == 'true') {
                        location.href = "/";
                    }
                };
                request.send('user_data=' + userData);
            }
        </script>
        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

What this is doing is creating a very basic login button. The button has a callback of `onLoginSuccess` which is called when the user logs in with Google. It then grabs the users token, via `user.getAuthResponse().id_token` and makes a post request to `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo` to verify the token (this can be done locally on your backend, Google provides libraries for it. However it's much easier to use the API endpoint). Once it is verified, it sends the response data to `authUser`, another function, which then passes it to the backend (`/login/login.php`) to actually start the user session.

> login/login.php

```php
<?php

session_start();

$user_data = json_decode($_POST['user_data']);

$_SESSION['user_data'] = $user_data;

echo 'true';
```

`login.php` simply starts a session, grabs the posted data, and sets the user session to the data posted. It then echos `true` so that the JavaScript knows it is done. The JavaScript then sends the user back the home page.

> profile/index.php

```html
<?php

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['user_data'])) {
    header('Location: /login');
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Profile</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src=<?php echo $_SESSION['user_data']->picture; ?>><br>
        <b>Welcome! <?php echo $_SESSION['user_data']->name; ?></b><br>
        <a href="/login/logout.php">Sign out</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

What this page does is first check if the `user_data` session is set. IF it is not set (meaning the user has not logged in), it redirects them back to the home page. If it is set (meaning they are logged in) then it displays a picture and the users name, and has a `logout` button. When this is clicked it simply brings the user to `/login/logout.php`.

> login/logout.php

```php
<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time()-3600, '/');
}
session_destroy();

header('Location: /');
```

All it does is remove all session data for the user, first getting rid of the session cookie and then destroying the actual session. It then leads them back to the home page. Clicking `profile` will now not allow them to view anything, because they are logged out, and will only display data when they log back in.

That is just a ***VERY*** basic and rough way of handling user sessions with the Google API. There are by far better ways (as this example has no real verification on the backend, and sessions are killed when the browser closes, so cookies may be better for you), however this is a general basis for handling user sessions.

Comment: Though this is a solution that will probably work, I must point out that the Google API actually _does_ handle login sessions for you. If you use the Google login button on two different pages, logging in on one will automatically log you in on the other when you open it.

Comment: I've barely worked with the API so I've got fairly limited knowledge on it. However while I was testing (for the answer I posted) I found that the Google login session did not persist, and prompted to sign in to Google each time I visited the page. Because of this I was required to store the session locally. However even so, the answer provided still does technically answer the question, as the login is not only stored and persisted but gives you the users information on the backend. But thank you for the note.

Comment: Google will only handle login sessions if the Google login button is placed on an actual domain (not `localhost` or a local HTML file).

Comment: This solution not work. PHP get a error message: ```session_start(): The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,'```