# Is there any way to identify through javascript if the browser and platform combination supports One tap sign-up and auto sign-in?

Tags: javascript, google-oauth, google-authentication, google-identity

As per One Tap sign-up and auto sign-in documentation
https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/troubleshooting

One tap sign-up and auto sign-in works in **some browser and platform combinations** and

> As the library is security sensitive, only the latest 2 versions of each browser is officially supported.

Is there any way through javascript to identify if the browser and platform combination supports one tap sign-up and auto sign-in.

Comment: the very page you've linked to says " Non-supported environments will always reject with a noCredentialsAvailable error."...so that would strike me as a good way to detect support.

Comment: noCredentialsAvailable error comes in more than 1 scenarios. For example it also comes when No signed in Google accounts are available

Comment: yes but there are other ways to detect if a user is signed in or not, so you can eliminate that as a possibility.

Comment: I am not sure how can we check if a user has an active gmail session in the browser or not.

Comment: Well I wasn't 100% certain either, but it seems logical to assume it's possible. So.... [here are some ideas](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=google+api+JavaScript+check+if+user+signed+in&rlz=1C1GCEU_en-GBGB820&oq=google+api+JavaScript+check+if+user+signed+in&aqs=chrome..69i57.5608j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) ...in particular [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43402843/how-can-you-detect-that-you-are-logged-out-with-the-google-login-api) looks promising. You can always try some of the other suggestions if that's no good.